# HTAccess 301 Redirect Issue with Coldfusion URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, coldfusion, http-status-code-301

Our web team recently rebuilt a Coldfusion site and are now setting up redirects.

The first redirect of the main inventory works fine but when I try to redirect each make like in the second one it redirects to  http://domain.com/inventory/pre-owned.php/make/carmake/

Basically the first redirect is overriding the second and replacing that part of the URL.

I think it may be an issue with the file index.cfm being the cutoff point.

```
Redirect 301 /folder/index.cfm http://domain.com/inventory/pre-owned.php
Redirect 301 /folder/index.cfm/make/carmake/ http://domain.com/inventory/pre-owned.php?sort=&make=Make&model=&year=
```

Is there any way to give one redirect priority over another or solve this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT: I could have sworn the answer below worked yesterday, but now it's not.

Strange thing is, I have another two lines like this:

```
Redirect 301 /new/index.cfm/page/testdrive/ http://domain.com/info/schedule-test-drive.php
Redirect 301 /new/index.cfm http://domain.com/inventory/new.php
```

and these work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Just rearrange your rules :

```
Redirect 301 /folder/index.cfm/make/carmake/ /inventory/pre-owned.php?sort=&make=Make&model=&year=

Redirect 301 /folder/index.cfm /inventory/pre-owned.php
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava! Although it would not work for me when using the $ and escape out the period, I simply flipped the two statements. Silly mistake, I thought I had tried that already.

Comment: Isn't the more specific rule supposed to appear before the more general rule?

Comment: For some reason, that worked. I have no idea why because for one, the more general rule is first, for the other one the more specific rule is first. But they both work for now.

Comment: Oh yes that's right my mistake, don't change the order. Can you show your complete .htaccess and tell me clearly which redirect isn't working for you. (Better to test from chrome dev tool or Firebug)

Comment: Also if it worked out for you, may I know why you un-accepted it?